# Moving Java Swing rectangle leaves rectangles behind

Tags: java, swing, awt

When I finally figured out the repaint method, I came to a problem. I want to move a rectangle across the screen, rather than re-drawing it again. Redrawing is fine, but it leaves the older rectangle behind it! This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tutorial3{

    public static void main(String[] agrs){
        createAndStartGui();
    }
    static void createAndStartGui(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("tutorial 3");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        f.add(panel);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Tutorial3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            panel.user.move("right");
            panel.repaint();
        }
    }
}

class MyRectangle{
    int x;
    int y;
    public MyRectangle(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    void move(String direction){
        switch (direction){
            case "up":
                this.y -= 10;
                break;
            case "down":
                this.y += 10;
                break;
            case "left":
                this.x -= 10;
                break;
            case "right":
                this.x += 10;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    MyRectangle user = new MyRectangle(10, 10);
    public MyPanel(){

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawRect(user.x, user.y, 10, 10);
    }

}
```

How do I get the rectangle that is left behind disappear (I DO NOT WANT TO CLEAR THE FULL WINDOW)? Or even better yet, how do I get the rectangle to 'move' (if it is possible)?

My end result:

[image]

What I want in the end:

[image]

Note: simply drawing the rectangle in that point isn't what I want. I want to see it getting dragged across.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only painting the rectangle, rather than the whole panel, so the panel ends up full of rectangles as you call the method. You need to draw the background of the panel too. This will "erase" the previous rectangles so the panel only has whatever you paint in that particular call and not what you did previously. To accomplish this you need to call:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

at the beginning of your `paintComponent` method (before drawing anything else). This works because the only thing that `paintComponent` needs to do in an empty JPanel is painting the background.

So:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.drawRect(user.x, user.y, 10, 10);
}
```

**EDIT:**

To answer some of your comments:

> I want to move a rectangle across the screen, rather than re-drawing it again.

There's no such thing as "moving" a rectangle. You can have things painted on the screen. If you want to see other things you have to paint those other things. There's no inherent "move the color of the pixels to the pixels...", that's not how it works. Do you want things? Draw them. Do you want them to move? Draw them repeatedly in different positions.

> (I DO NOT WANT TO CLEAR THE FULL WINDOW)

But you do. You want to repaint the whole panel each time something has to change. If there are other things in the panel that you don't want "erased" then repaint them.

To be clear, it would be possible to only clear the "old" rectangle position and paint a new one, without affecting the rest of the panel. But that is unnecesarily tricky. When you override `paintComponent` calling `super.paintComponent(g)` in the first line is the standard procedure. Not putting it has to be a very conscious decision and you better are sure of what are you doing.

If your program is done in a way that part of your code misbehaves when you repaint the background of your panel, I can tell you with confidence that is those parts that aren't well designed and not that calling `super.paintComponent(g)` is a bad idea.

`paintComponent` has the responsibility of painting the whole component. The background is part of the component. It's natural, and good design within Swing, to do it when you override it.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I presume that this will also work when redrawing more than 1 component at a time (e.g. a background such as non-moving shapes will also be re-drawn).

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm not sure I understand your comment, what do you mean "redraw more than 1 component at a time"? `super.paintComponent` will just fill (clearing evertything) the area with the background color, you can then draw as many shapes as you want over it.